# Converting incoming data in the form of "multipart/form-data" into a Querydict object

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert a data like below to QueryDict object. Is there a ready-made class that can do this job? I could not parse the data that came in the form of the "multipart/form-data" as I wanted. So I need help

```
data = {
    'name': 'erhan',
    'last_name': 'koçlar',
    'gender.code': 1,
    'gender1.gender2.gender3.gender4.code': 1,
    'tags[5]': 'TAG_2',
    'tags[0]': 'TAG_1',
    'tags[1]': 'TAG_2',
    'persons[0].name': 'erhan',
    'persons[1].name': 'ercan',
    'files[0].file': 'file1',
    'files[0].name': 'file_name_1',
    'section_files[0]': 'file2'
    'rows[0][0]': 'col_1',
    'rows[0][1]': 'col_2',
    'rows[1][0]': 'row_1',
    'rows[1][1]': 'row_2'

}

#after convert
data = {
    'name':'erhan',
    'last_name': 'koçlar',
    'gender': { 'code': 1 },
    'gender1': { 'gender2': { 'gender3': { 'gender4': { 'code': 1 } } } },
    'tags': [ 'TAG_1', 'TAG_2', 'TAG_2' ],
    'persons': [ {'name':'erhan'}, {'name':'ercan'} ],
    'files': [ {'file': 'file1', 'name':'file_name_1' }],
    'section_files': [ 'file2' ],
    'rows': [ [ 'col_1', 'col_2' ], [ 'row_1', 'row_2' ] ],
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can do the Job. Note the modification I changed `files[0].name` to `files[1].name` as it would overwrite the field `0`.

```
import re

data = {
    'name': 'erhan',
    'last_name': 'koçlar',
    'gender.code': 1,
    'gender1.gender2.gender3.gender4.code': 1,
    'tags[5]': 'TAG_2',
    'tags[0]': 'TAG_1',
    'tags[1]': 'TAG_2',
    'persons[0].name': 'erhan',
    'persons[1].name': 'ercan',
    'files[0].file': 'file1',
    'files[1].name': 'file_name_1',
    'section_files[0]': 'file2',
    'rows[0][0]': 'col_1',
    'rows[0][1]': 'col_2',
    'rows[1][0]': 'row_1',
    'rows[1][1]': 'row_2'

}

def buildSubDict(dkey,value):
    keys = dkey.split('.')
    while keys:
        cdict = {keys.pop():value} 
        value = cdict
    return cdict

def buildArray(keys, uniqueName, data):
    aSize = None
    for key in keys:
        match =re.findall('[(\d+)]',key)
        m = [[int(m)] for m in match]
        if not aSize:
            aSize = m
        else:
            aSize = [a + b for a,b in zip(aSize,m)]
    
    aSize = [max(i)+1 for i in aSize]

    res = ''
    while aSize:
        res = [res if isinstance(res, str) else res.copy() for n in range(aSize.pop())]
    
    for key in keys:
        match =re.findall('[(\d+)]',key)
        ndim = [int(m) for m in match]
        templst = []
        citem = res
        for idx in ndim:
            new = citem[idx]
            if not isinstance(new, list):
                citem[idx] = data[key]
                data.pop(key)
                break
            citem = new
    data[uniqueName]=res

newKeys = {}
for key in dict(data):
    subkey = None
    if '.' in key:
        sDict = buildSubDict(key,data[key])
        data[list(sDict.keys())[0]] = sDict[list(sDict.keys())[0]]
        data.pop(key)

uniqueKeys = set([i.split('[')[0]  for i in data.keys() if '[' in i ])

for ukey in uniqueKeys:
    subkeys = []
    for key in data:
        if ukey+'[' in key:
            subkeys.append(key)
    buildArray(subkeys, ukey, data)
```

After processing, `data` will look like this:

```
{'name': 'erhan', 
 'last_name': 'koçlar', 
 'gender': {'code': 1}, 
 'gender1': {'gender2': {'gender3': {'gender4': {'code': 1}}}}, 
 'section_files': ['file2'], 
 'persons': [{'name': 'erhan'}, {'name': 'ercan'}], 
 'rows': [['col_1', 'col_2'], ['row_1', 'row_2']], 
 'tags': ['TAG_1', 'TAG_2', '', '', '', 'TAG_2'], 
 'files': [{'file': 'file1'}, {'name': 'file_name_1'}]}
```

Also note the different implementation of `tags`, compared to your question. You can filter out the `''` by setting them to `None` instead and then do a list comprehension `[i for i in myList if i]` to filter them out.

Comment: Only the data created with the "files" key is incorrect. in your example it is 'files': [{'file': 'file1'}]}. There is no 'name' key in dict.  But what I want is 'files': [{'file': 'file1', 'name': 'file_name_1'}] – 
erhan
 2 hours ago

Comment: There is a situation that I do not understand, every time I run the script while testing, it sometimes works, sometimes gives an error. the error it gives is


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/django_projets/betik_app_person/core/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    buildArray(subkeys, ukey, copy_data)
  File "D:/django_projets/betik_app_person/core/test.py", line 43, in buildArray
    aSize = [max(i) + 1 for i in aSize]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable `